# how to return single row using TableAdapter

Tags: c#, sql-server, datatable, dataset, datarow

Hi I am currently using TableAdapter that returns a dataTable, which is fine to use when result table should have more than one row like :

```
MyItemsDataTable myItemsDataTable = Adapter.GetAllItems();
```

but if we need only one row as a result, say an item, which has a particular ID

```
MyItemsDataSet.MyItemRow  itemRow = Adapter.GetItemByID(id)[0];
```

how can I make Adapter to return one row instead of DataTable.
I am using DataSet Designer wizard and gives me two options for putting in SELECT statement

```
Use SQL statements -->  Select which return rows
(returns one or many rows)
Use SQL statements -->  Select which returns a single value rows
(returns a single value)
```

and using similar query

```
SELECT * from
FROM  FOOD_ITEMS
WHERE (ITEM_ID = @ITEM_ID)
```

Do I need to override this method or add a new one ?

```
public virtual MyItemsDataSet.MyItemsDataTable  GetItemByID(int ITEM_ID)
```

probably something like

```
public virtual MyItemsDataSet.MyItemRow GetItemByID(int ITEM_ID)
```

If so, I cannot do it in designer generated file !! where can I do this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a new Select statement in the Dataset Designer.  Use `Select which return rows`.  Then use the following query:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * from 
FROM  FOOD_ITEMS 
WHERE (ITEM_ID = @ITEM_ID)
```

Save this method as `GetFirstItemByID()` or something similar.

---

For the googlers out there, many of the non-MS databases (eg. MySQL) will use the following syntax instead:

```
SELECT * from 
FROM  FOOD_ITEMS 
WHERE (ITEM_ID = @ITEM_ID)
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Great, query now returns single row but I still have to fetch it from [0] index of the DataTable. Any way we to add method that returns row instead of DataTable, but using above query ?

Comment: Right-click the dataset file and hit *view code*. It should open `DatasetName.cs` (*NOT* `DatasetName.designer.cs`). Create a new method in the dataset that simply does `return GetFirstItemByID(id)[0];`

Answer (score 3):

I believe the only way is to access the first row in the data table via an index, as you are doing with this query -

```
MyItemsDataSet.MyItemRow  itemRow = Adapter.GetItemByID(id)[0];
```

Another thing you should consider is dumping table adapters and using LINQ2SQL instead. LINQ supports the .FIRST() method, which does precisely what you want.

Comment: I am already doing this, I need alternative. Some problems with testing.